# INVALID JSON FORMAT JQUERY

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jax-ws, prototypejs

**Hi guys.** I get a problem, when i try to make ajax to my JAX-WS service( i use google jsonwebservice library).
So on my page i have this code:

```
function submit(){
         var JSONObject= '{sayHello:{name:"alexei"}}';
         console.log(JSONObject);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:  '/jaxwsExample-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/json/hello',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(JSONObject),
                dataType: 'application/json',
                async: true,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("DATA " + data);
                }
            });
     }
```

And console.log(JSONObject); returns to me:

```
{sayHello:{name:"alexei"}}
```

But when in my TomCat server i got this error:

**Caused by: com.jaxws.json.codec.JSONFault: Invalid JSON input : "{sayHello:{name:\"alexei\"}}"**

But also i got working example from http://code.google.com/p/jsonwebservice/wiki/GettingStarted

In that example used prototype.js framework which made an ajax call:

```
 function submit(){
            new Ajax.Request('/jaxwsExample-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/json/hello', {
                method: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                postBody: '{"sayHello":{"name":"'+$('name').value+'"}}',
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    $('response').update(transport.responseText).setStyle({ background: '#FFFFAA' });
                    $('notice').update(transport.responseText.evalJSON().message).setStyle({ background: '#dfd' });
                }
            });
        }
```

**But i want to use jquery instead of prototype.js, can you help me whats wrong with my jquery ajax call or with JSON  object?**

Comment: Wrap the keys in your JSON obect in quotes: `{"sayHello":{"name":"alexei"}} `

Comment: I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "object" is actually a string.

```
var JSONObject= '{sayHello:{name:"alexei"}}';
```

So when you later call `JSON.stringify` the quotes get escaped.  Either start with an actual object,

```
var JSONObject = {sayHello:{name:"alexei"}};
```

...or don't attempt to stringify a string.

Comment: thx man, you were right, but now on ajax succes function doesnt execute
...  
success: function(data) {
         console.log("DATA " + data);
}

Comment: solved, i remove  -> dataType: 'application/json' propertie from .ajax()

Comment: `dataType` is normally automatic anyway so it isn't needed.  Also `async` is always true so you don't need to specify that either.